# Recursive struct realloc fails

Tags: c, recursion, memory, struct, realloc

I've got something like this written for an university project, a basic AI for a basic "game":

```
struct ai_config{
    float followup_mul;
    float aggro_ratio;
    int wisdom;
};

extern struct ai_config global_AI;

struct ai_move {
    int pngn;
    int coords[2];
    float aggro;
    float safety;
    int order;
    struct ai_move* followup;
    int followup_size;
};
```

And there is this function:

```
int assess_moves(struct Gmdt* gmdt, struct ai_move** ai_arr, int count, int xpos, int ypos, int order, int pg){
    if (order >= global_AI.wisdom) return 0;

    int dir, dist;
    struct ai_move* temp;

    for (dir = 1; dir <= 6; dir++)
        for (dist = 1; dist < estimate_mvmnt_adv(gmdt, xpos, ypos, dir); dist++)
            if(check_move_ai(gmdt, xpos, ypos, dist, dir)){
                count++;
                temp = (struct ai_move*)realloc(*ai_arr, count * sizeof(struct ai_move));
                if (temp == NULL){
                    printf("[AI]\tMemory reallocation error! (Order #%d)", order);
                    return -1;
                }
                else {
                    (*ai_arr) = temp;
                    (*ai_arr)[count-1].pngn = pg;
                    (*ai_arr)[count-1].coords[0] = polar_to_x(xpos, ypos, dir, dist);
                    (*ai_arr)[count-1].coords[1] = polar_to_y(xpos, dir, dist);
                    (*ai_arr)[count-1].order = order;
                    (*ai_arr)[count-1].aggro = assess_aggro(gmdt, &((*ai_arr)[count-1]));
                    (*ai_arr)[count-1].safety = assess_safety(gmdt, &((*ai_arr)[count-1]));
                    (*ai_arr)[count-1].followup_size = assess_moves(gmdt, &((*ai_arr)[count-1].followup), 0, (*ai_arr)[count-1].coords[0], (*ai_arr)[count-1].coords[1], order+1, pg);
                }
            }
    return count;
}
```

Called like this in a loop in the main.c:

```
struct ai_move* moves;
if(gmdt.phase == 1)
{
     int x, y, n = 0, c;
     for (y = 0; y < gmdt.rows; y++)
        for (x = 0; x < gmdt.columns; x++)
            if (gmdt.map[x][y] == '1'){
                c = n;
                n = assess_moves(&gmdt, &moves, n, x, y, 0, -1);
                printf("\n[AI]\t%d moves would be possible from the (%d, %d) position.\n", n-c, x, y);
            }
}
```

It works perfectly when global_AI.wisdom is set to 1. But when I set it to 2, the realloc returns NULL, on order equal to 1, even though the same error wouldn't occure at the same point with global_AI.wisdom set to 1. Why could that possibly be? Am I missing something?

Comment: When "it works perfectly" with `global_AI.wisdom == 1`, what is the value in `order`?  Does it work perfectly because it takes the early exit?

Comment: The compiler will optimize it, but the repeated `(*ai_arr)[count-1]` in the `else` clause is ugly.  I'd create a local pointer and dereference that, if I didn't decide to use a compound literal assignment `temp[count-1] = (struct ai_move) { .pngn = pg, .coords = { polar_to_xpos(…), … }, … };`.  I might well not use the compound literal assignment.  I'm mildly surprised at the asymmetry in the argument lists for `polar_to_xpos()` and `polar_to_ypos()` — I would have expected them to be identical.

Comment: I don't find where you initialize the `moves` variable in `main`. You passed a pointer to the uninitialized `moves` variable to `assess_moves`, which at some point does a `realloc` on it. `realloc` works only with `NULL` or a previously `malloc`/`realloc` allocated pointer. I don't see where your code meet these conditions.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler
It's for university, doesn't have to look nice, just has to work. And the asymmetry is a result of this being a 2d map being forcefully transposed into a hexagonal map.
When it works well, the order value is either 0 or 1. Then when I increase wisdom to 2, it crashes when order is 1, that's what confuses me.

Comment: @Pablo
It indeed started to work after malloc'ing it first, so problem solved I guess. But the thing is - why did that happen? Why did it work for a smaller limit and then stopped working for a bigger one? And how come realloc works with a previously malloc *or* realloc allocated pointer? I mean if that was the case, I wouldn't have to init it.

Comment: @JackJaxCaster because passing to `realloc` an initialized pointer is undefined behaviour, meaning that anything can happen. So it's almost impossible to make a prediction.